# How to do this jQuery/CSS animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

So, a client of mine saw this animation on [this website](http://www.todaythe12.com/#section_about) (scroll to see the faces of the team and hover over them to see the animation) and wants me to do something similar (only with different colors).
Problem is, I've no idea how they achieve it, I am somewhat new to these kind of things.

Does anyone know if that's a plugin or something. I took a look at their code and JS files and all I can see they use is a plugin called [Parallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/) to do the particles animation, but that was all I could figure out.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: that page takes days to load

Comment: good lord, how did your client even see this page? I literally had to restart my computer, it crashed chrome so bad O.o

Comment: It's a great animation but the site does take forever to load! I don't know, I'm thinking I'm gonna have to charge more for that haha. When I saw it I thought it was a simple plugin that did all the work, silly me.

Answer (score 2):

Right click   their page is showing lot of java scripts.

I think their using
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit for jQuery Transit - CSS3 transitions and transformations

Scroll down and their website shows lot of animations

rotate like this

```
$('.box').css({ rotate: '30deg' });
```

moves around like this

```
$('.box')
  .transition({ x: -40 })
  .transition({ y: 40 })
  .transition({ x: 0 })
  .transition({ y: 0 });
```

many other code is there only look there once

sorry my english not very good

Comment: Thanks! I had missed that plugin, I'll give it a look along with the rest!

Answer (score 1):

They use 3 different images in html + 5 in css style (background-image) and this script (I found it in script.js - use Chrome DevTools/sources)

```
$('.face').on('mousemove',function(e){
    var MyoffsetY = e.offsetY;
    var MyoffsetX = e.offsetX;

    if($.browser.mozilla){
        MyoffsetX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        MyoffsetY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    }


    var Top1 = (MyoffsetY/30);
    var Left1 = (MyoffsetX/30);
    var Top2 = MyoffsetY/5;
    var Right2 = 3-(MyoffsetX/35);
    var Top3 = 15-(MyoffsetY/10);
    var Left3 = MyoffsetX/10;


    $(this).find('img').eq(0).css({'top':Top1+'%','left':Left1+'%'});
    $(this).find('img').eq(1).css({'top':Top2+'%','right':Right2+'%'});
    $(this).find('img').eq(2).css({'top':Top3+'%','left':Left3+'%'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, I saw that script too but understood nothing haha, bad thing is the website I'm working on generates the faces via php on a query with wordpress, so it will be a little harder to add the images via CSS, but not impossible I guess. I even reached the developer on the website to see if he can share any code or something, hope he answers! I'll share it if he does.

Comment: I think this script only help to move black points in the direction of mouse cursor (direction-aware hover effect) - something like this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/. All of the rest is the css-rules  background-position of images changes on hover + transform - you can see it in firebag